# What is the pivotal quantity

Tags: probability, statistics, statistical-inference

I had a question of two parts. I solved the first part but I am stuck on the second. Any hints or partial solutions would be greatly appreciated.

a)$ X_1,....X_n$ are uniform iid on the interval $(0,\theta)$. If $Y=max(X_1,....X_n)$ find the pdf of Y?
 I worked the pdf to be $n \dfrac{\bigl(\dfrac{x}{\theta}\bigr )^{n-1}}{\theta}$

b) Construct a random variable $T = g(Y;\theta)$ such that T has the same distribution as Y for all values of $\theta$ . Such a random variable T will then be a pivot?
I am honestly not sure where to start with this one?

Comment: "Construct a random variable T=g(Y;θ) such that T has the same distribution as Y for all values of θ" Well, T=Y.

Answer (score 1):

A pivot is a random variable $T=g(Y;θ)$ such that $T$ has the same distribution for all values of $θ$ (and not what is written in the question). If one notes that $X$ uniform on $(0,\theta)$ means that $X/\theta$ is uniform on $(0,1)$, one can guess that $T=Y/\theta$ is indeed a pivot. Can you check this?

More generally, if the density of some random variable $Z$ depending on $\theta$ has the form $f_Z(z\mid\theta)=g(z/\theta)/\theta$ for some function $g$ then $g$ is a PDF and $Z/\theta$ is a pivot.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer Did. just to make sure: so I was wondering if there was a rule to deriving the pivot? I mean you mentioned that one can guess it but I worry that I may not guess it right?

Comment: The last sentence gives such a rule, but of course all situations do not fit in it.